# NSight Profiling - How to address "Pipe Busy" stalls?

Tags: cuda, nsight

After using NSight to profile my CUDA app, I see this under "Issue Efficiency":

[image]

After clicking the helpful Help link in the panel pictured above, I found this description in the docs:

**Pipeline Busy** — The compute resources required by the instruction are not yet available.

Any suggestions on figuring out which compute resources are not yet available, and why?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, it means the warp scheduler cannot issue an instruction because the pipeline is full. Possibly because you're using many [low throughput instructions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#arithmetic-instructions__throughput-native-arithmetic-instructions).

Comment: @Cicada Looks like it was arithmetically bound. I rearranged some stuff to improve ILP which knocked the register usage from 38 to 17, and reduced the stall pipe busy stall to about 12%. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run pipe Utilization experiments to see what's busy. From the [User Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition/4.1/Nsight_Visual_Studio_Edition_User_Guide.htm#Analysis/Report/CudaExperiments/KernelLevel/PipeUtilization.htm%3FTocPath%3DAnalysis%20Tools|CUDA%20Experiments|Kernel-Level%20Experiments|_____8):

> Each Streaming Multiprocessor (SM) of a CUDA device features numerous
>   hardware units that are specialized in performing specific task. At
>   the chip level those units provide execution pipelines to which the
>   warp schedulers dispatch instructions to. For example, texture units
>   provide the ability to execute texture fetches and perform texture
>   filtering. Load/Store units fetch and save data to memory.
>   Understanding the utilization of those pipelines and knowing how close
>   they are to the peak performance of the target device are key
>   information for analyzing the efficiency of executing a kernel; and
>   also allows to identify performance bottlenecks caused by
>   oversubscribing to a certain type of pipeline.